# displaying as lockscreen background

Tags: android, lockscreen

[image: lockscreen background]

this is the requirement of my app I can able to show app when screen is locked but I can't able to show app as lockscreen background in the above picture, anyone suggest me to acheive this.]

Comment: Create wallpaper in your app and listen for lock screen intent, when its fire just change wallpaper on lock screen programmatically. Your question is too broad please be specific.

Comment: If we use lockscreen intent it shows the wallpaper when screen is locked not as background of lockscreen. I want lockscreen as transperant and at background I want to show the app.

Comment: You do realize that some manufacturers (Samsung for one) do not allow apps to programatically change the lock screen background?